# Assembler на Kali linux

Tags: linux, ассемблер

Недавно поставил дистрибутив Kali linux x64, И хотел бы установить на него что-то типо fasm подскажите как и как Скомпилировать?

Comment: А там репозитории есть?

Comment: По поводу fasm: один из очевидных вариантов - скачать с [официального сайта flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/download.php), распаковать и запустить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

у вас прямо сейчас стоит «AS - the portable GNU assembler», который входит в пакет *binutils*. краткую справку смотрите командой:

```
$ man as
```

---

ещё часто используют, например, *nasm* из одноимённого пакета.

---

а вообще в репозиториях должно присутствовать множество реализаций всяких ассемблеров. см. вывод:

```
$ apt-cache search assembler
```

Answer (score 4):

Ассемблировать:

```
nasm -f elf64 -l Listing_filename.lst Source_filename.asm
```

Собирать:

1. Если метка входа - `_start`:

   ```
   ld -o Output_filename Source_filename.o
   ```
2. Если метка входа `main`:

   ```
   gcc -o Output_filename Source_filename.o
   ```

Comment: И nasm, и ld с gcc на Кали предустановлены